# Изменение модификатора доступа в производном классе

Tags: java, ооп

Можно ли изменить модификатор доступа в производном классе? Есть класс «А» с методом `public some()` и наследник класс «В», у которого нужно изменить модификатор доступа у метода `some()`. Еще было бы интересно увидеть какие-нибудь комментарии по поводу полей с изменением доступа у наследника.

Comment: Опишите полностью конкретный кейс, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть такая важная вещь как **[принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)** (цитата с Википедии):

> Пусть q(x) является свойством, верным относительно объектов x некоторого типа T. Тогда q(y) также должно быть верным для объектов y типа S, где S является подтипом типа T.

Роберт С. Мартин [определил](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf) этот принцип так:

> Функции, которые используют базовый тип, должны иметь возможность использовать подтипы базового типа, не зная об этом.

Принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков **является основной полиморфизма** - одного из ключевых понятий объектно-ориентированного программирования.

Относительно модификаторов доступа используется терминология "большая или меньшая видимость" ('more / less visible').

**Метод или поле нельзя сделать менее видимым**, то есть понизить видимость с `public` до `protected`, например. Причина в том, что это нарушит принцип подстановки.

Однако, **можно повышать видимость метода или поля**:

- `protected` -> `public`
- `package` -> `protected`, `public`

Вот код, который демонстрирует различные случаи изменения уровня доступа при наследовании. Его можно целиком [скачать из репозитория](https://github.com/NickVolynkin/PackageAccessTest).

```
public class Parent {

    //package access
    void foo() {
    }
}

public class ChildPublic extends Parent {

    // Legal
    @Override
    public void foo() {
    }
}

public class ChildProtected extends Parent {
    // Legal
    @Override
    protected void foo() {
    }
}

public class ChildPrivate extends Parent {
    // Illegal
    /*
    @Override
    private void foo() {
    }
    */
}

public class SamePackageAccessTest {
    {
        new Parent().foo();

        //these have overriden foo()
        new ChildPublic().foo();
        new ChildProtected().foo();

        //this one had not overriden foo()
        new ChildPrivate().foo();
    }
}

package otherpackage;
import test.*;
public class OtherPackageAccessTest {

    {
        //Legal!
        new ChildPublic().foo();

        //illegal
        /*
        new ParentPackage().foo();
        new ChildProtected().foo();
        new ChildPrivate().foo();
        */

    }
}
```

Это перевод собственного ответа на EN.SO: [What means “methods without access control can be declared more private in subclasses” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350797/2790048)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @azaznioo пожалуйста. Сам рад, что вспомнил про этот ответ.

Answer (score 0):

При переопределении метода у класса наследника, мы не можем изменить модификатор доступа на более закрытый.

Например, если метод public, то в классе наследнике не получится уровень доступа изменить на private.

Что довольно логично, раз класс-родитель предоставляет нам свой метод в качестве открытого, то и класс-потомок не должен ограничивать доступ к этому методу, так как иначе изменится интерфейс класса. Это сделано для того, чтобы гарантировать, что объект класса-наследника мы можем использовать везде, где можно было бы использовать объект супер-класса.

Это отсылает нас к SOLID, а если быть точнее, то к L - The Liskov Substitution Principle.

Класс наследник должен дополнять, а не изменять базовый.

Answer (score -1):

Да, можно понижать уровень доступа к функции в производном классе через override.

```
public class Shape {
   public String getName() { return this.name; }
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
   private String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

Comment: А вот и нельзя. Такой код не скомпилируется. `Shape a = new Circle(); a.getName();` как должно работать?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin: Какой текст ошибки компиляции? a.getName(); не должен работать потому что доступ закрыт.